# Insert .pdf doc or .png image content into a .docx file using java

Tags: java, pdf, png, apache-poi, docx

How can I insert pdf or png content into a docx file using java?

I've tried using [Apache POI API](https://poi.apache.org/) in the following way, but it is not working (it generates some junk doc file):

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();  
String pdf = "D://capture1.pdf"; 
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf); 
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader); 
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) { 
  TextExtractionStrategy strategy = parser.processContent(i,new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());    
  String text = strategy.getResultantText();        
  XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();  
  XWPFRun run = p.createRun();     
  run.setText(text);        
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);   
} 
FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream("D://javadomain1.docx");    
doc.write(out1);   
out1.close();   
reader.close();   
System.out.println("Document converted successfully");
```

Comment: .doc (Word document) and .docx (Word XML document) are two very different formats. Looking at your code it seems you want to generate the latter (correct me if I'm wrong), so I edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide input/output examples and the libraries and versions you are using? I've tried your code with poi-ooxml 3.11 and itextpdf 5.5.4 and the file at http://www.energy.umich.edu/sites/default/files/pdf-sample.pdf and it seems to work just fine (here is the full class: http://pastebin.com/Q9ccH4CN and the pom file for building a project with those dependencies using Maven: http://pastebin.com/6TXUiuQP)

Comment: I am using  this jars itextpdf-5.4.4.jar and poi-ooxml-3.7.jar.My pdf contain charts generated in d3.js.Its generating empty doc file.thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with POI, and you can certainly do it using docx4j.

[Here's sample code](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ImageAdd.java) for inserting an image using docx4j.

Note that to "insert a PDF", you need to OLE embed it. That's more difficult, since you need to convert the PDF to a suitable binary OLE object.  In docx4j, helper code for doing this is part of the commercial Enterprise edition.